# jQuery datatables plugin : Get json from server and displaying table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I need to fetch JSON from server and display the same in table. I am unable to map JSON object from the server to the DataTable plugin.

This is my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = null;
    $(function () {        
        vm = new TestViewModel();        
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#testtable').dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetFiles", "Home")',                
                "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "id" },
                { "mData": "createDate" }               
                ]               
            }); 
        });        
    });
```

This is my Controller code(Action) :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetFiles()
        {
           /*
           var result = /*Get object from database*/
           */
           return this.JsonSerialize(result)
        }
```

Need some guidance here on how to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have model for MVC pattern:
    [DataContract]
    public class TestViewModelResult : ServiceResult
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "prototypes")]
        public List<PrototypeResult> Prototypes { get; set; }
}

I change script for page:

<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = null;
    $(function () {        
        vm = new TestViewModel();        
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#testtable').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": false,
                "sAjaxDataProp": "prototypes",
                "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetFiles", "Home")',                
                "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "id" },
                { "mData": "createDate" }               
                ]               
            }); 
        });        
    });
After that work fine
```